# Use another button instead of back button

Tags: android, back-button

I have a problem with using back button in android. I know I can use onBackPress() method to handle it, but I need a way to do the event of the back button inside onResume lifecyle. The reason why I have to do it this way, is I have started a timer in another class from the onResume method. And when I press the back button this timer should stop. But when I use the onBackPress() method to stop it I got a NullPointerException because the timer never started. When I use a button to stop the timer which is inside the onResume method then the timer stops correctly. So the quastion is can I use another button instead of back button?
Or how can I use the event of the back button inside onResume when the user press it?

Comment: You cannot react to key events within other lifecycle methods, as key events are delivered in their own callbacks which cannot occur until you have returned from any existing UI thread callback.  Most likely you need to re-architect your design and use either explicit state flags, or implicit ones (such as seeing if the thing that is causing your NPE is non-null before you try to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to do this kind of extra work, if you need all this things just because of timer nullpointer write below condition before stopping timer.

make your timer variable `public static` and then

```
if(YouActivity.timer!=null)
   YouActivity.timer.stop();
```

Comment: It was as simple as you said. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably creating the timer as a variable or child of the original `Activity`. When that `Activity` is paused (or off-screen) the variable could be destroyed. This is why the button works (same `Activity`) and not `onBackPressed` which is called in another `Activity`.

You need a static variable or global variable running on another thread - like a `Service` or in the `Application` object. The `Application` object is a last resort, so look into `Service` first.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` before calling `onBackPressed()`

From
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.